# IOS 8 - Deny IOKit notice - Whats causing this

Tags: ios, ios8, xamarin, console, iokit

I am using multipeer/ibeacon framework to discover and communicate between IPAD devices. I was debugging a issue w.r.t random disconnections in the session thats established between ipads and found the following message in the console of all devices happening from time to time

```
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOMACAddress
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOMACAddress
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties HiddenInterface
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOInterfaceState
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IONetworkData
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOInterfaceNamePrefix
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOBuiltin
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOLocation
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IORequiredPacketFilters
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOActivePacketFilters
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOInterfaceType
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOMaxTransferUnit
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOInterfaceFlags
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOInterfaceExtraFlags
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOMediaAddressLength
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOMediaHeaderLength
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOInterfaceUnit
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOPrimaryInterface
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties BSD Name
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOClass
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOPropertyMatch
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOProviderClass
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties CFBundleIdentifier
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOProbeScore
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOMatchCategory
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOActiveMedium
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOSelectedMedium
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOLinkStatus
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOLinkSpeed
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOMediumDictionary
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOFeatures
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOMaxPacketSize
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOMinPacketSize
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOPacketFilters
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOMACAddress
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOGeneralInterest
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties USBDeviceFunction
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties StartedTimestamp
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IsActive
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOCFPlugInTypes
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOUserClientClass
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties FinalizedTimestamp
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties FinalizedDurationMS
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties NetworkConfigurationOverrides
Jul 14 17:13:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SET(249) deny iokit-get-properties IOMACAddress
```

This once started happening continued to happen very often as soon as i establish another round of testing. However when i tested today, i wasnt able to observe this.

Since this ( i think ) results in disconnection of multipeer session when happens and , i want to know more information on what causes this. Insight will really help.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem and I see the same log messages. Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: I found that if i create more sessions ( say 6 - 8 ) at the same time, i experience this problem. if i create one by one , then i couldnt replicate this problem.